# MySQL query not working after adding AND operator

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty sure i messed up the quotes, but can't find where exactly. It stopped working after adding the `AND` operator. Can anybody guide me to the right direction?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_table WHERE p_num=".$w[0] AND l_num='.$w[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_table WHERE p_num='".
                      $w[0]."' AND l_num='".$w[0]."'"
                     );
```

Basically, you messed up w/ opening/closing quotes.
What error message did PHP return to you? Most of the times, if not always your solution lies therein.

Answer (score 0):

You broke your query string. See this difference

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM pl_table 
     WHERE p_num='".$w[0]."' 
     AND l_num='".$w[0]"'");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the quotes, your AND needs to be inside the quotes, and it is not.
Yours:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_table WHERE p_num=".$w[0] AND l_num='.$w[0]);
```

What it should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_table WHERE p_num=".$w[0]." AND l_num=".$w[0]);
```